# UWP EmailMessage with several to recipients doesn't work with Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, uwp

I'm having the same issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935407/sending-email-to-multiple-recipients-from-uwp-store-app), there is no way to open a new email to multiple recipients from UWP when the default email app is Outlook instead of the UWP Mail App. The pstar's explanation is exactly the behavior I get on my side. This feature is very important for LOB apps.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. It has been a logged issue in our system.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried mailto:user1@work.com%3buser2@work.com

this seems to work correctly for me

Comment: I've tried it, but I get an invalid hostname exception when I try to build the Uri to pass it to LaunchUriAsync: var uri = new Uri("mailto:user1@work.com%3buser2@work.com");
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

Comment: @AsierPeña
It will work if you put this mailto:user1@work.com%3buser2@work.com in your edge browser directly.

Comment: @FangPeng-MSFT Yes, if I put that uri in edge it works, but how can I get it working from UWP? The Uri class constructor only works with one email address.

Comment: @BugFinder there is no difference if I use mailto: or mailto://, same happens with the separator, there is no difference using ";" or "%3b" to separate each email address. The UWP Uri constructor only works with one email address

Comment: @AsierPeña, I have reported this issue in our system. Thanks for your patient.